# How to exponentiate binary variables in QUBO-type problems?

Tags: optimization, modeling, quadratic-programming, unconstrained-optimization, qubo

**Ising Model**

In an Ising model, the Hamiltonian of one configuration of spins $\vec{s}$ is:

$$ H(\vec{s}, \mathcal{J}, \mathcal{h}) = \sum_{i} h_{i} s_{i} + \sum_{i \ne j}J_{ij} s_{i}s_{j} $$

where each spin $s_{i} = \pm 1$.

The partition function of an Ising model is:

$$Z(\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{h}) = \sum_{\vec{r}} \exp \left [ H(\vec{r}, \mathcal{J}, \mathcal{h}) \right]$$

The summation is over all possible configurations and $r_{i} = \pm 1$ for all $i$.

---

**Question**

How to formulate the exponential of binary variables in the partition function for QUBO-type problems?

Answer (score 2):

Luckily in this case, the exponential can be treated in a way very similar to how we're already familiar. If we use the example that I chose in [my answer to your recent question](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/6620/727), we would have, where your $\vec{r}$ is just $(s_1,s_2)$:

$$\tag{1}
Z=\sum_{s_1,s_2} e^{\left(\mathcal{J}s_1s_2 + hs_1\right)}.
$$

If $\mathcal{J}=2.5$ and $h=3$, then we would have:

\begin{align}\tag{2}
\hspace{-15mm}Z &\hspace{-5mm}= e^{\left(2.5(-1)(-1) + 3(-1)\right)} + e^{\left(2.5(1)(-1) + 3(1)\right)} + e^{\left(2.5(-1)(1) + 3(-1)\right)} + e^{\left(2.5(1)(1) + 3(1)\right)} \!\!\! \\
\tag{3} &\hspace{-5mm}=e^{2.5-3}+e^{-2.5+3}+e^{-2.5-3} + e^{2.5+3}\\\tag{4}
&\hspace{-5mm}=246.951.
\end{align}

A more challenging, but separate, question would be how to keep something like Eq. 10 from that answer linked above, in QUBO format when we are exponentiating binary *variables* such as when $\mathcal{J}$ and $h$ are not known constants but are instead written using several binary variables.

Comment: When the number of spins is 50, the number of possible configurations is $2^{50}$. That means $2^{50}$ terms in that equation. This seems to be impractical for 50 spins.

Comment: Correct. Maybe you can switch from {-1,1} to {0,1} and can figure out ahead of time which ones give an energy of 0, for example in my case when s1=0 you don't even need to check the s2 cases. However at 50 spins things will be hard.